# Ignoring/skipping updated_at does not work in the Paper Trail gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paper-trail-gem

I've got a model called `Page` which with the following `has_paper_trail` configuration:

```rb
class Page < ApplicationRecord
  has_paper_trail versions: { class_name: 'Versions::PageVersion' },
                  only: %i[structure],
                  limit: 10
end
```

I'm only interested in tracking the changes to the `structure` column, everything else can be ignored. If I `.touch` the record, a new version is created by PT. Even if I add `skip: %i[updated_at]` to the `has_paper_trail` configuration, a new version gets created anyway.

I'm not sure if it's intended behaviour or not. And if it is, how can I avoid the creation of a new version when the `updated_at` timestamp is updated?

Comment: Hi wout. I'm pretty sure this exact question has shown up as a GH issue before, but I can't find it (https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail/issues?q=touch) It's probably not the behavior we want, and is probably due to https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/33429

Answer (score 0):

I've added

```rb
has_paper_trail skip: %i[create_at updated_at]
```

and it works good!

P.S.

```
Ruby 2.7.2
Rails 6.1.3.1
PaperTrail 12.0.0
```